# Bottom fixed dropdown-menu scrolls through the page on Mobile Safari

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, mobile-safari

I’d like to have a dropdown fixed to the bottom of my Page. It works fine with Chrome Mobile, but Safari iOS 7 scrolls to the end of the page if I open the dropdown.

css:

```
div {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

html:

```
<div>
    <select name="sizes" size="1" id="select">
        <option value="1">Size: 1</option>
        <option value="2">Size: 2</option>
        <option value="3">Size: 3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please provide an Image or the URL,You can create an snippet too.

Comment: Sure: danieleytan.com/select.html

You see my problem when you open this link in Mobile Safari and open the dropdown-menu on the bottom.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have the same issue with Safari users on my PHP/Laravel website. When they use any dropdown they get sent to the bottom of the pages. This is only with Safari. Going nuts here trying to figure out why.